# Cannot install anything using yum in redhat 6.2

Tags: rhel, yum

I've recently ran some commands to resolve an issue with an installation of `libgcj` package from [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/203603) page. I think I removed some repositories from my computer. Anyway I cannot install anything using `yum install <package-name>` after that. It returns an error

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package libgcj available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

also while updating using `yum update` it is not working and gives this error

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Running `yum repolist enabled` command gives this

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
repolist: 0
```

Can somebody show how to fix this?

Here is the content of the rhel-source.repo file

```
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Source  
baseurl = ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

[rhel-source-beta]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever Beta - $basearch - Source 
baseurl = ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/beta/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-
beta,file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

Comment: You should provide your yum config file(s) within your question

Comment: Where can I find that ?

Comment: If you `man yum`, the relevant configuration files for your system will be listed in the `FILES` section near the end of the page.

Comment: I updated the question with the configuration files found in the man yum command.

Comment: The *contents* of those files....

Answer (score 2):

I do not currently have a RHEL system to check the official repos. What you should do is the following:

- make sure you have an active subscription (`subscription-manager list --available --all`)
- check if `yum repolist` will list any repositories (which you have done already)
- check the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory for the .repo files. If the directory is not empty, check if the files do not have `enabled=0`. If they do, edit to `enabled=1` or simply delete the line
- if you do not have any .repo files in yum.repos.d, then recreate them - as said, I do not have a RHEL system on hand right now, but the bare minimum is the following:

  ```
  [repository]
  name=repository_name
  baseurl=repository_url
  ```

Check [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html) for more info on adding a repository.

Comment: I had the `rhel-source.repo` and I enabled it as you said. It shows in the repolist. But I still can't update or install using yum command

Comment: The `yum repolist` command shows the `rhel-source.repo` but with a `status` 0. why is that

Comment: Do you have a Red Hat subscription?   Show us the contents of your `rhel-sources,repo` file.

Comment: I updated the question with the rhel-source content

Comment: The rhel-source.repo seems to be fine - after enabling the repo, try to execute the following commands to clear the cache and rebuild it: `yum clean all` and `yum makecache`